# Remove horizontal lines in custom searchbar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have the custom searchbar displayed below.
I am trying to remove the horizontal lines that are showing up on all four edges of
the searchbar in the image below.

I have tried the following setting the different search bar elements to white, but that does not seem to help.
I have pasted my code below

Control

```
public class CustomSearchBar : SearchBar
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
                     BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSearchBar));

    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderWidthProperty =
              BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderWidth), typeof(int), typeof(CustomSearchBar));

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the Border Color of the SearchBar.
    /// </summary>
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the Border Width of the SearchBar.
    /// </summary>
    public int BorderWidth
    {
        set { SetValue(BorderWidthProperty, value); }
        get { return (int)GetValue(BorderWidthProperty); }
    }
}
```

IOS Customer Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSearchBar), typeof(CustomSearchBarRenderer))]
namespace Mobile.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        private UIColor BorderColor = UIColor.Black;
        private int BorderWidth = 3;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var searchbar = (UISearchBar)Control;

            var newElement = ((CustomSearchBar)e.NewElement);    

            BorderColor = new UIColor(red: 0.56f, green: 0.58f, blue: 0.62f, alpha: 1.00f);
            
            if (newElement.BorderWidth != 0)
            {
                BorderWidth = newElement.BorderWidth;
            }
        
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
    
                const string searchField = "searchField";
                Foundation.NSString _searchField = new Foundation.NSString(searchField);
                var textFieldInsideSearchBar = (UITextField)searchbar.ValueForKey(_searchField);

                textFieldInsideSearchBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                textFieldInsideSearchBar.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
                //   searchbar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                //   searchbar.BarTintColor = UIColor.White;
                searchbar.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
                searchbar.Layer.CornerRadius = 32;
                searchbar.Layer.BorderWidth = BorderWidth;
                searchbar.Layer.BorderColor = BorderColor.CGColor;
                searchbar.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
                
                searchbar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(new UIImage(), UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);         
                

                searchbar.TextChanged += delegate
                {
                    searchbar.ShowsCancelButton = false;
                };
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So how I ended up getting a border round the seachview was to use a wrap the customsearchview with a frame, in my case i ended up using yummypancakeview

see below :

```
  <yummy:PancakeView
                Padding="0"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WhiteBackground}"
                CornerRadius="30">
                <yummy:PancakeView.Border>
                    <yummy:Border Color="{StaticResource SearchViewBorderColor}"
                                  Thickness="3"/>
                </yummy:PancakeView.Border>                   

                <controls:CustomSearchBar
                  Placeholder="Search by name, postcode or place"
                  PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource SubHeadingColor}" />   
            </yummy:PancakeView>
```